# R: Assign certain items of a variable into defined groups

Tags: r

Let's say I've a variable with 594 different items.

```
[1] "qwerty"
[2] "qwerta"
[3] "qwerto"
[4] "qwerte"
etc.
```

What I'd like to achieve is to group the items into new predefined categories. For example, the items ranging from levels [1] to [85] belong to category "A":

```
    workclas<-factor(levels=c("A", "B", "C"), ordered=T)
    workclas[levels(x)>=1 & levels(x)<85]<-"A"
    workclas[levels(x)>=85 & levels(x)<272]<-"B"
    workclas[levels(x)>=272 & levels(x)<594]<-"C"
    workclas[x=="Refusal" | x=="Don't know" | x=="No answer"]<-NA
    table(workclas, exclude=NULL)
```

I was thinking of 'aggregate' but that doesn't work obviously.

```
    aggregate(formula, data, FUN, ...,
    subset, na.action = na.omit)
```

Also I can't use 'split' since I don't have a reocurring and identical element to split by.

```
    split(x, f, drop = FALSE, sep = ".", lex.order = FALSE, ...)
    split(x, f, drop = FALSE, ...) <- value
```

How would I solve this in R?

Thank you for your efforts!

Thomas

Comment: See `?cut` perhaps

Comment: Thank you for that valuable input! I think that was it. I tried this and it worked: workisco = cut(workisco, 
        breaks = c(1,8,52,171,279,319,375,401,486,542,590), labels = workclas, right = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

The short input of User A. Webb was much appreciated. 
This is what I did, if anyone else is struggling with a similar problem:

```
workisco<-as.numeric(workisco)
workclas<-factor(levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), ordered=T)
workisco = cut(workisco, 
    breaks = c(1,171,279,590),
    labels = workclas,
    right = TRUE)
```